# Divisibility of $a^p-r$ and $a^q-r$ by the primes $p,q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p, q$ be prime and $a$ some positive integer such that $a = pq + r$ where $r$ is the remainder. Show that $p \mid a^p – r$ and $q \mid a^q – r$.

Example: $p = 3$ and $q = 5$, $a = 17$ and $r = 17 – 3\cdot5 = 2$:
$$\begin{align*}\frac{17^5 – 2}5
                                     &= \frac{1419857 – 2}5\\
                               &      = 1419855/5\\
                     &                = 283971\end{align*}$$

Comment: Not that it is very relevant to the question, but which remainder is $r$ precisely? Is it the remainder when $a$ is divided by $pq$?

Comment: @barto : No it's not the remainder when _a_ is divided by _pq_! It is actually _a ≡ r_ (mod _pq_).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Corollary to Euler's Theorem: For prime $p$ and integer $a$, $a^p\equiv a \pmod{p}$

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to mention Fermat too.